Create an outline of borders simulating sea level rise using QuickMapServices with QGIS
I understand that this is a very simple question, but I can't understand how to do this and I have read a bunch of forum posts on this topic to no avail. I would like to do a seemingly simple operation to create a simple map. I find the UI of QGIS to be really confusing, so if there is a programmatic way to do this operation that would be helpful.
Basically, what I want to do this is this:

Start with a layer of the world map with topographic data, I am using OpenTopMap.
Select a specific region of the Earth (in my case the US states WA, OR, and Canadian province BC) and clip it.
Redraw the sea level to show a rise in sea level of x meters.
Then remove everything but the coastline data to create a 4k resolution PNG or SVG of just the coastline as a black line.

I just can't seem to get any selection I make show up. Is this possible using just OpenTopoMap? I have tried to use other GIS data provided by USGS of specific regions of Washington state, but even then I can't get that to work.
I have even tried to forgo rising the sea level and just showing the coast lines as is. I found the OSM coastlines data and well my computer just chugs trying to load that file and make the selection, only for all my selections to just be blank... I assume that's why it's best to use the online maps.

The maps in quickmapservices are just pictures, you need to get some actual data

I mentioned trying to use OSM coastlines data, but creating a selection is time consuming and then every time I do it, it just outputs a blank selection. Using this data, what object would my selection have to be to be able to see it? Is it a Shapefile layer?
